# Eclipse 4 Replacement for WorkbenchWindow restoreState and closeAllPages

Tags: eclipse, migration, rcp, e4

Eclipse 3.* had the method `restoreState` and `closeAllPages` for the WorkbenchWindow. What is the 4.* replacement?

I have thousands of persisted `WorkbenchWindow saveState(IMemento memento)` results in a database. I need to either convert them somehow, or use them to layout the views and perspectives in an e4 application.

If I convert them, are there any tools for doing this, and how would I use the converted result? Is there any way I can parse what I have persisted, then do the layout programmatically and lastly persist the layout with the e4 format?

My paradigm in the RCP client is a little bit special, we do not implicitly save the settings, instead we explicitly save the settings and load them on start up, and can reload specific settings on an adhoc basis.

Answer (score 1):

`WorkbenchWindow` is an internal class and not part of the Eclipse API. You should not use methods which are only defined in internal classes [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

This class has been substantially rewritten in Eclipse 4 and direct equivalents of non-API methods are not available.

The `restoreState` method in particular looks like it would be immensely difficult to re-engineer. The Eclipse 4 code simply does not use the `IMemento` format to save window states anymore, all state information is saved in the EMF XMI format. The old `restoreState` method also called several other internal methods in other classes most of which no longer exist.

Comment: You are correct, but I have inherited the migration task nevertheless. Do you have any pointers for a pragmatic way to re-engineer what resoreState does in 3.*?

Comment: Looking at the old code for restoreState it looks like it would be very, very difficult to redo. I updated the answer with some info on this.

Comment: After playing around with it I agree. However there must be another way to approach the problem. I have extended my original post to include some other possibilities.